# html link get variable address bar php

Tags: php, html, variables

Have html links including a variable.

```
<a href="cwexchange.php?o=opt1" id="opt1" title="Opt1">Option1</a>
<a href="cwexchange.php?o=opt2" id="opt2" title="Opt2">Option2</a>
```

which goes to next page, and for some reason I am getting always option 1 when I echo the citi variable even when I have clicked option2 and it shows in the address bar. Did I miss something here?

```
$cit = "";
$citi = "";
// Make sure the _GET cit is set, and sanitize it
if(isset($_GET["o"])){
$cit = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['o']);
} else {
header("location: example.org");
exit(); 
}

//////////option page routing
if ($cit = "opt1"){$citi = 'Option 1';} 
else if ($cit = "opt2"){$citi = 'Option 2';}
```

Comment: It should be `==` to compare, not `=`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289635/if-statements-not-working

Comment: You're right, I thought I had already tried that. Oops, thanks for saving me time though Barmar, appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

As @Barmar said it should be comparison not assignment. Like this

```
$cit = "";
$citi = "";
// Make sure the _GET cit is set, and sanitize it
if(isset($_GET["o"])){
$cit = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['o']);
} else {
header("location: example.org");
exit(); 
}

//////////option page routing
if ($cit == "opt1"){$citi = 'Option 1';} 
else if ($cit == "opt2"){$citi = 'Option 2';}
```

But I suggest you to use switch since it works faster:

```
$cit = "";
$citi = "";
// Make sure the _GET cit is set, and sanitize it
if(isset($_GET["o"])){
$cit = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['o']);
} else {
header("location: example.org");
exit(); 
}

//////////option page routing
switch ($cit) {
    case 'opt1':
        $citi = 'Option 1';
        break;
    case 'opt2':
        $citi = 'Option 2';
        break;
}
```

Comment: `=`  is not "equation", it's assignment :P

Comment: Please don't bother posting answers to questions like this. I think this slows down their automatic deletion.

Comment: Thanks Pamblam, just getting back from Christmas vacation and need to get the ball rolling again.

Comment: Thanks @Pamblam for correction.

Comment: also, consider ternary instead of switch. 8 line of code condensed into one - `$citi =  $cit == "opt1" ? "opt 1" : "opt 2";`

Comment: It is less code but still slower than switch.

Comment: I think that I'll use switch, I have 500 or more cases though