# if with many else if only work until 3 tries doesnt work when it reaches 4

Tags: php, if-statement

```
    $oride='';
    $count = "25";
    $origin = $_POST["origin"];
    $destinataion = $_POST["destination"];
    $oride = ($destination = $_POST["destination"] - 
    $origin= $_POST["origin"]);

    if ($oride <="0"){
        echo "invalid";
    }
    elseif ($oride <="15"){
        echo $count;
    }
    elseif ($oride ="16"){
        echo $count + "1";
    }
    elseif ($oride ="17"){
        echo $count + "2";
    }
```

if statement is ok until $oride ="16" but when it reaches $oride ="17" it still choes 26 it should be 27

Comment: It should be `==`, not `=`.

Comment: Hint: `$x=y` *assigns*.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289635/if-statements-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is assignment operator. You need `==` or `===`(if data type also need to equal) for comparison

```
$oride='';
$count = "25";
$origin = $_POST["origin"];
$destinataion = $_POST["destination"];
$oride = ($destination = $_POST["destination"] - 
$origin= $_POST["origin"]);

if ($oride <="0"){
    echo "invalid";
}
elseif ($oride <="15"){
    echo $count;
}
elseif ($oride =="16"){
    echo $count + "1";
}
elseif ($oride =="17"){
    echo $count + "2";
}
```

Comment: ty bro it was helpful