# Loop not working as it should

Tags: php, mysql

Below is a broad overview of my environment

Databases:

1. Tsql Database = SysAid
2. MySql Database = Bounties
3. MySql Database = Gamification

So what the code does is:

- Manager loads bounty for SysAid request on bounty database, it gets a   status 1 if active 0 if not active, and 0 for incomplete.
- Code checks this and displays bounty on screen (different code)
- User claims bounty by completing the request on SysAid
- Code checks sysaid if request is completed and then updates the bounty  database to say it is completed and mark it as inactive.

However for some reason everytime the cron runs this piece of code to check if the bounty is completed it marks it as inactive even though it is still incomplete.

Here is my code below, it should check for a closed status on sysaid and then update the table. however it just changes the status without the ticket being closed.

```
    <?php
$servername = "*.*.*.*.";
$username = "*";
$password = "*";
$dbname = "Gamification";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Failed : " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM performance_bounties";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ticket_number = $row['ticket_number'];
    $bounty_value = $row['bounty_value'];
    $bounty_completed = $row['completed'];
    $bounty_completed_by = $row['completed_by'];
    $bounty_enabled = $row['enabled'];
    check_sysaid($ticket_number, $bounty_value, $bounty_completed,     $bounty_completed_by, $bounty_enabled);
}


function check_sysaid($ticket_number, $bounty_value, $bounty_completed, $bounty_completed_by, $bounty_enabled) {

    $servername = "*.*.*.*";
    $username = "*";
    $password = "*";
    $dbname = "Gamification";

    $conn2 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn2->connect_error) {
        die("Connection Failed : " . $conn2->connect_error);
    }

    putenv("TDSVER=80");
    putenv("FREETDSCONF=/etc/freetds/freetds.conf");
    putenv("ODBCSYSINI=/etc/odbcinst.ini");
    putenv("ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini");


    $myServer = "TS";
    $username = "*";
    $password = "*";
    $database = "SYSAID";

//connection to the database
    $dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $username, $password)
    or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

//select a database to work with
    $selected = mssql_select_db($database, $dbhandle)
    or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

    $sysaidcheckquery = "
  SELECT id, substring(responsibility,11,11) as responsibility, status from service_req where id = '" . $ticket_number . "'";

    $sysaidcheckresult = mssql_query($sysaidcheckquery);
    $numRows = mssql_num_rows($sysaidcheckresult);

    while ($sysaidrow = mssql_fetch_array($sysaidcheckresult)) {
        echo $ticketstatus;
        $ticketid = $sysaidrow['id'];
        $ticketresponsibility = $sysaidrow['responsibility'];
        $ticketstatus = $sysaidrow['status'];

    if ($ticketstatus = "27") {
        $bountysqlupdate = "UPDATE performance_bounties SET enabled = '0', completed = '1', completed_by = '" . $ticketresponsibility . "' WHERE ticket_number = " . $ticket_number;
        $performanceupdate = "UPDATE performance_q3_2018 SET bounties = '" . $bounty_value . "' where user_name = '" . $ticketresponsibility . "'";

        if ($conn2->query($bountysqlupdate) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn2->error;
        }

        if ($conn2->query($performanceupdate) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn2->error;
        }
    }


    }



}



?>
```

Comment: can you `var_dumo(sysaidcheckresult)`?

Comment: Learn to use an IDE with a debugger (Eclipse, of one of your choice). Set a breakpoint, step through the code, line by line, examining the values of your variables and following the logic. You would have easilly spotted the problem and would not have needed to ask here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning (`=`) instead of comparing (`==`).

```
$ticketstatus = "27"
```

will always evaluate to true. It should be

```
if ($ticketstatus == "27") {
```

Comment: Questions like these should just be closed as typos. Don't waste time posting an answer.

Comment: @Barmar Good to know. I wasn't aware that questions can be closed (or flagged for closing) because of typos. I was originally looking for a duplicate to flag it as such but a quick search didn't bring anything up.

Comment: Here's a dupe in C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289635/if-statements-not-working. But we had a meta discussion a couple of years ago and the concensus was to close them. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312052/canonical-question-for-typo-for

Comment: Typos are part of the "Cannot be reproduced" close reason.

Comment: @simon thank you for your help i did miss that completely. Barmar please note not everyone is at the same skill level and people do sometimes miss things. Aint that what this site is for? Anyway simon thanks it is working now.

Comment: @Barmar Got it. I voted to close the question now too